# Deleting table entries based on checked checkboxes

Tags: php, database

I have a list of items, each row with a checkbox. Each checkbox has a unique name like "65" or "77" corresponding to an item_ID from the database. I want to be able to

```
DELETE FROM $table WHERE "name of checkbox"=item_ID AND "checkbox is checked"
```

Basically remove any data entries corresponding to a ticked checkbox in that table row.
The checkboxes are constructed as such and appear at the end of every row:

```
$field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$ID=$field['item_ID'];

<input name='".$ID."' type='checkbox' value='yes'>
```

Comment: if you echo the $_POST value of a checkbox input, you'll see why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

set their names to be $ID[], and in the server-side do a foreach loop on $_REQUEST[$ID].

Answer (score 0):

Because in Forms only checkboxes are posted via POST which are checked you need to solve this with a little trick. For every entry add a hidden field in your html code like

```
<input type='hidden' name='ids[]' value='".$ID."'>
<input name='checkbox_".$ID."' type='checkbox' value='yes'>
```

after posting this stuff to your server you should have the array $_POST['ids'] containing all rows which have been displayed to your user. so iterate over it and check wether the corresponding checkbox index is present:

```
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $checkId) {
    if(array_key_exists('checkbox_'.$id, $_POST) {
         // delete the entry
         $sql = 'delete from your_table where id = "'.$id.';"';
         // execute sql
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you could fetch the original list again from the DB like in your example (`$field=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $ID=$field['item_ID'];`) and you wouldn't need the hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

another trick:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_$iID">
...
</form>

foreach ($_POST as $post) {
$temp=explode('_',$post);
if ($temp[0]=="checkbox") {delete $temp[1]....}
}
```